# What type of mathematical function is this?

Tags: functions, exponential-function

As per the attached gif. Can anyone tell me what type of mathematical function this trend is plz? and corresponding equation?
Linear is there for comparison.

[image]

thanx!!!

Comment: [Context](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#9960)? Where did you encounter that image, for example? Presumably it ought to have been accompanied by some explanation of what $C$ is and what the graphs represent.

Comment: i agree but unfortunately not.
what family of functions does this belong to. would it be fair to say this was some form of exponential decay?

Comment: my comment didnt make sense when read back. to affirm, i dont have any context or additional text to offer other than the figure itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without any more context, you can use the following function to generate a similar figure.

$$
y = \frac{5000}{10}\left(10^{r(c)}-x^{r(c)}\right)^{\frac{1}{r(c)}}
$$
with $x\in[0,10]$, where
$$
r(c) = \frac{1}{1-\exp(-\alpha(c^{\beta}-\gamma))}
$$
where $\alpha=5, \beta=0.02, \gamma=0.8$ leads to a figure very similar to what you showed.

As for the name, it looks like one side of an $L^p$ [ball](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space#/media/File:Vector-p-Norms_qtl1.svg) (see $L^p$ spaces).

However, this is only a guess given the little context we have.

Comment: Thanks. $L^p$ polygon is not taught in calculus nor real analysis I guess, where is it taught specifically please?

Comment: Sorry, I used the wrong name for the figure. It shouldn't be a "polygon" but a "ball". The first time I encountered $L^p$ balls/spaces was in a functional analysis course. The idea behind what I said is very simple. The typical euclidean ball (circle in 2D) is $(x^2 + y^2)^{1/2} = 1$. The $L^p$ ball is something like  $(|x|^p + |y|^p)^{1/p} = 1$ for arbitrary $p\geq 2$. If $p=2$ you recover the euclidean ball. If $p\to\infty$ to obtain a square. I just mapped the $c$ in the figure to a suitable $p$.

Comment: thank u very much for this answer. its very very interesting. i never knew about this. so if I were to describe this function I would say it is an Lp ball? 
is there not a simpler alternative? like a power series of the type $y=ax^{b} + c$

Comment: There might be other alternatives. This is the simplest I can think of right now. Regardin what you mentioned $y=ax^b+c$ might work too, but you will sacrifice symmetry. As for the name, you can say that the function was generated using a$p$-norm. It is not an $L^p$ ball since it is not uniform, just like a circle is not an hyper-ellipse. Hope this helps!

Comment: In my previous comment i meant to say "just like an ellipse is not always a circle". The other way around. Sorry.

Comment: Thanks @FeedbackLooper =)